# what happens if we try to apply toString for String Literal?

Tags: java

Could you please help me out on this?

I am trying to apply toString method on String Literal if i do so will String literal gets Convered to string object ?  If it gets converted to String object will memory be allocated in heap or String Constant pool ?

Here is the code Snippet that i am trying:

```
String str = "Welcome";     
System.out.println(str.toString());
```

I Could not figure out what is taking place internally with `str.toString()` this statement.

Comment: I would be surprised if `String#toString` didn't simply return `this`

Comment: here i could get the value of str as "Welcome", but  what i am asking is whether this outcome welcome is String literal type or string object type?

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString()) is fairly clear about this: *"This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned."*

Comment: i have gone though it , now i understood the concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look at the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/tip/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l2141) for the [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString()) method:

```
/**
 * This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.
 *
 * @return  the string itself.
 */
public String toString() {
    return this;
}
```

So the `toString()` method does nothing but return the exact same `String`

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple, String class overrides `toString()` from Object and returns `this`.

Implementation:

```
public String toString() {
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`str` already is a `String`, so `toString()` will not result in anything besides returning `str`.

Comment: I think I got a little confused, I thought of primitive type when talking about literal.

Answer (score 0):

the toString in this case is redundant code because it have no effect on the str